# Where is the CleanUp method?

Tags: subsonic3

I'm working fine with Subsonic 3 and the templates until november 2009.  Now I'm geting the source directly from Git, but the ActiveRecord template doesn't generates correctly anymore.   In the line 334 of the ActiveRecord template for SQLite:

```
return from items in repo.GetAll() 
where items.<#=CleanUp(fk.OtherColumn)#> 
==  <#=CleanUp(fk.ThisColumn)#>
```

Error:  The name 'CleanUp' doesn't exist in the current context

But I can't find the CleanUp method in the Subsonic.Core project.  Someone knows something about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no more remedy than a  [version of the method](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/issuesearch?state=open&q=cleanup#issue/24) to Settings.ttinclude.  Now Structs.tt doesn't generates.